# find_scope! error - Could not find a valid mapping ... (Rails and Devise 1.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Error Message:

```
Could not find a valid mapping for #<Event id: 10022, event_name: "test", start_date: "2011-03-31", end_date: "2011-03-31", event_description: "test", created_at: "2011-03-30 03:26:01", updated_at: "2011-03-30 03:26:01", is_ecommerce: false, is_secure: false, event_password: nil, notify_rsvp: false, user_id: 20, start_time: "noon", street_address: "", city: "", state: "", country: "", zipcode: "", website_url: nil, status: "Draft", payment_received: false, is_confirmed: false>
```

Here is the top part of my Full Stack Trace:

```
devise (1.2.1) lib/devise/mapping.rb:40:in `find_scope!'
devise (1.2.1) lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:29:in `confirmation_path'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:163:in `edit'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
```

I've recently Updated: Devise 1.2.1 (I also received the error with 1.2.0)
Rails 3.0.5
Ruby 1.8.7
WEBrick 1.3.1

Also, I have this in my routes:

```
devise_for :users
```

I used to run fine till the latest updates.
 Thanks

Comment: I should also note: that the app/controllers/events_controller.rb:163 is the following:

`redirect_to(confirmation_path(@event), :notice => 'Your event has not been confirmed.')`

My route looks like this:

`match '/admin/events/confirmation/:id' => "events#confirmation", :as => 'confirmation'`

Comment: should it be confirmation_event_path(@event)? what is the route for "events@confirmation" when you run "rake routes"

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your helper `confirmation_path` is being overridden by devise's url_helpers.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb

Basically, devise thinks you want a confirmation path for your event.

Change your route to be something like

```
match '/admin/events/confirmation/:id' => "events#confirmation", :as => 'confirmation_event'
```

and then use

```
redirect_to(confirmation_event_path(@event), :notice => 'Your event has not been confirmed.')
```

in your controller and anywhere else you were using it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your code for multiple `devise_for :events` declarations. This has been the cause of such an exception in my case, as it surely confuses Devise.